# Unknown apps - My Consumer Cellular and Prip

Tags: applications, privacy, motorola

I've purchased MotoG4 Plus (Unlocked) around Summer 2016 at Amazon(India). I've been using the phone since then and have been extremely cautious about the apps I use on my phone.

Whilst playing through some settings on Pushbullet (under setting: Notification Mirroring > Choose which apps to enable), I've noticed an app named My Consumer Celluar who's logo looks similar to this [playstore listing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cci.usage&hl=en) and two apps named Prip who's logo looks similar to this [listing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.motorola.ptt.prip&hl=en).

[image: Prip]    [image: My Consumer Cellular]

I've never installed these apps before and these apps are not listed under Android App Settings for me to simply uninstall.

Atleast, the android app id for Prip is `com.motorola.ptt.prip` which makes sense because I have a Motorola phone. But, I have no idea about Consumer Cellular.

My questions:

1. Why did Motorola install these apps even though it was sold in a different market ?
2. How are these apps not visible under general android app settings ?
3. Do these concealed apps work in the background thus invading my privacy? If so, How could one know that the apps are running in the background ?

Comment: It's probably your carrier added bloatware. Check with them first

Comment: Re: "*How are these apps not visible under general android app settings*", have you checked "show system" (or something similar, might be different from device to device) inside your general Android app settings menu?